# How to Determine the Metric Distance between a Point and a Convex Set?

Tags: convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

**Question**:

For a non-empty set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, define the distance from $x$ to $A$ by $d_A(x) = \inf_{y\in A}||x-y||$. Prove that if $A$ is convex, then $d_A(x)$ is a convex function.

**Attempt**:

We draw a straight line through points $x, x_1$ and $x_2$ so that $x = \lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2$. Then, we connect these dots to a circle, which represents set $A$, since our goal is to find the distance between $x$ and the circle. So, we will have:

$d_A(x) = d_A(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2) = \inf_{y\in A}||\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2-y||$.

My challenge is, I can’t see where I will apply the condition that says “if $A$ is convex…”. If I should write $y$ in convex form (since $y\in A$), I suspect I will run into trouble.

I would really appreciate any help from you guys.

Comment: Triangular inequlity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$, and $y_1\in A$ and $y_2\in A$ such that,

\begin{align}
\left\|x_1 - y_1\right\| &\le d_A(x_1) + \epsilon\\
\left\|x_2 - y_2\right\| &\le d_A(x_2) + \epsilon 
\end{align}

Then $\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2\in A$ and,

\begin{align}
d_A\left(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2\right) & \le \left\|\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2 - (\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2)\right\|\\
&\le \lambda \left\|x_1 - y_1\right\| + (1-\lambda) \left\|x_2 - y_2\right\|\\
&\le \lambda d_A\left(x_1\right) + (1-\lambda) d_A\left(x_2\right) + \epsilon
\end{align}

Now $\epsilon \to 0$ and you will have what you are looking for

Comment: My concern is the choice of $\lambda$ for both $x$, a point outside of the set, and $y$, a point in the set. Is it really okay to use the same constant? (I used different constants and couldn’t resolve it. That was what I meant by **running into trouble**)

Comment: But why do you have that concern? Just use one for $x$ and use the convexity as I show in my answer.